# Export current gridview data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, export-to-excel

I'm using this code to export my gridview data. I have a dropdown in my page and when I select dropdown values the data changes in gridview and I need to export only that present data into excel.

```
protected void ExporttoExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();   
}
```

I am using paging and when I export initially without having selected dropdown values I need to export all the data, but now only the datas in the first page alone gets exported.

Can anyone correct me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom made method for exporting excels in a formatted style from a Datatable-Gridvieww. You can use it, by assigning to the table variable your Datatable in which you bind the Gridview( the whole datatable before the paging)

```
private void ExportToExcel(DataTable table, GridView gv)
    {

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Charset = your charset//"Windows-1253";
        Response.ContentEncoding = your encoding//Encoding.UTF8;
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=test.xls";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
          "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
          "style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
        int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

        for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td style='background-color: #C0C0C0;' align=" + "center" + ">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td align=" + "center" + ">"); ;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and not able to export gridview to excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the SQL query result in a DataTable and save that DataTable in a ViewState or session. Then when clicking the export button, **retrieve the DataTable from the ViewState** and create a dummy GridView that will have the DataTable as its source.

Something like this:

```
   protected void ExporttoExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //First, retrieve the DataTable from ViewState
       DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
       Dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DtData"];

       //Now you have the data, create a dummy GridView that will be used for exporting
       GridView grdView = new GridView();
       grdView.AllowPaging = false;
       grdView.DataSource = Dt;
       grdView.DataBind();

       //Do the Exporting stuff
       Response.Clear();
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
       System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
       System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
       grdView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
       Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
       Response.End();
   }
```

This way, each time you change the dropdownlist value, save the selected SQL query result in a datatable and then in the ViewState and export.

Of course, if you can update your question with the dropdownlist code or how are you setting the GridView datasource, I'd update this answer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the `GridView` paging then render. You may need to do the binding as well.

```
protected void ExporttoExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    // ************************
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false; // <- disable paging then render
    // also do the binding
    GridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    // ************************

    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

**Edit (working example)**

ASPX (`GridView` and an export `Button`):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="grd1_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Student Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FatherName" HeaderText="Father Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGridView();
    }
}

private void BindGridView()
{
    using (var dtStudent = this.GetStudentData())
    {
        this.grd1.DataSource = dtStudent;
        this.grd1.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataTable GetStudentData()
{
    var dtStudent = new DataTable();
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("StudentID");
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("StudentName");
    dtStudent.Columns.Add("FatherName");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var sIndex = i.ToString("00");
        dtStudent.Rows.Add("Student-" + sIndex, "Name-" + sIndex, "Father-" + sIndex);
    }

    return dtStudent;
}

protected void grd1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    this.grd1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGridView();
}

protected void ExporttoExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    // ************************
    this.grd1.AllowPaging = false; // <- disable paging then render
    this.BindGridView();
    // ************************

    this.grd1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (this._Export)
        this.ExporttoExcel();
    else
        base.Render(writer);
}

private bool _Export = false;

protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._Export = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't export all the datas. It exports only 1st page datas.

Comment: OK then you may need to do the binding again after resetting the paging as well.

Comment: Now the gridview doesn't even export.

Comment: @Vicky, I am NOT sure how you are exporting, I have added a working example here.